# API cannot accept a string with "\" character in it .NET6

Tags: c#, json, api, escaping, .net-6.0

I'm working on an API in .NET6. One of my endpoints is a POST, takes in a comma-separated string array.

So like below:

```
{
   "data":
   [
       "f", "fo", "foo", "food"
   ]
}
```

One of the strings in this string array contains the backslash character i.e. \ .

So the API doesn't even hit the endpoint in the controller, instead it returns a 400 saying

```
'Q' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped.
```

when the letter Q follows the backslash.

E.g. if the data looked like the below:

```
{
   "data":
   [
       "f", "fo", "fo\qo", "food"
   ]
}
```

Note: the letter Q is irrelevant here.

Now, a work around for this is to escape this, by putting another backslash in front of the existing backslash, and that works fine, but I  don't want clients to have to change a process on their end.

Is there anyway I can allow the \ character to come through in a string, or get my API to escape it somehow?

Comment: Creating valid json for a POST is a pretty client side problem and should be handled there. If you try to fix it server side somehow you presumably get in trouble with those clients that will do it correctly.

Comment: Yep, at best what you're creating isn't json, it's something custom you defined. Just look at that top example you posted, that isn't valid json at all.

Comment: @Blindy I've update the "data" tag to be surrounded in quotes and removed the quotes surrounding the JSON strings, misplaced them earlier.... if that's what you meant by it not being valid JSON.

Comment: When you get your example from a client that does encoding correctly would you then use two backslashes? Without enforced encoding you can't distinguish between an escaped backslash and two backslashes and with trying to fix this on the server you help the ones doing something wrong and punish those doing it correctly.

Comment: An option you have if you need that "broken" behavior somehow desperately then create versioned apis. So create a new version of this endpoint with the correct behavior. Then all current clients needing the "broken" behavior use the v1 version and "good" clients then can go to the v2 version of your api.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like I'll have to ask clients to escape special characters on their end, thanks for your input.